# Как убрать прокрутку ListView

Tags: android, listview

Здравствуйте! Как можно сделать так, чтобы скроллился не ListView, а Layout, в котором этот ListView находится? Тоесть сделать так, чтобы ListView вывелся полностью, а из-за его большого размера прокручивался Layout. Заранее спасибо

Comment: Никак. Хотите чтоб лэйаут сколился -размещайте на нем элементы и оборачивайте в `ScrollView`

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете использовать вот этот кастомный класс, вместо стандартного `ListView` в своем layout-e:

```
public class NonScrollListView extends ListView {

    public NonScrollListView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public NonScrollListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public NonScrollListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int heightMeasureSpec_custom = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec_custom);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
        params.height = getMeasuredHeight();
    }
}
```

Но нужно, чтобы он находился внутри `ScrollView` для скроллинга. Но, так делать **крайне не желательно**, потому что с этим методом recycling у элементов `ListView` перестает работать. Соответственно, если у вас будет много данных в `ListView`, UI будет заметно тормозить.

Пример использования:

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
      <com.mypackagename.widgets.NonScrollListView
          android:id="@+id/poi_list"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: @SlowAR Заблокировать прокрутку виджета, который специально для этого предназначен , чтобы потом прокручивать его через задницу - не самое лучшее решение. Если вам надо решать такую задачу, значит вы все делаете неправильно.

Comment: Мне необходимо вывести два ListView, в которых будет находится достаточно много информации, но если в первом ее будет столько много, что не будет влезать в экран, в результате я смогу скроллить только первый ListView, ибо до второго будет просто не достать,  поэтому я хотел узнать, можно ли сделать как-то так, чтобы прокручивалось все сразу, а не каждый ListView по-отдельности

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, что в этом случае в LinearLayout можно вставить два  FrameLayout с равным  android:weight , в каждый из которых вставить по ListView